# Существует ли глагол «аукать»?

Tags: лексика, глаголы, терминология, междометие

Первое: существует ли глагол "аукать", как производный от междометия "ау"?
И второе: к какому разряду можно отнести данное междометие? Ведь, с одной стороны, ты заблудился и пытаешься побудить окружающих помочь, а с другой — выражаешь сожаление, страх.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, конечно, такой глагол существует.

[АУ́КАТЬ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/8114), -аю, -аешь; несовер. (разг.). Кричать «ау!».
| однокр. аукнуть, -ну, -нешь.
| сущ. ауканье, -я, ср.

*И уже перекликались голоса над берегом, **аукали** в парке* (А. Гайдар. Военная тайна).

*Печальное эхо отозвалось в скалах на берегу Варгана, пробежало по водной глади до зеркального плеса, переметнулось на другую сторону реки, а там, как заблудившиеся ягодники, стали перекликаться и **аукать** ущелья гор* (В. Шустов. Тайна горы Крутой).

**Ау** — это призыв откликнуться; относится к императивным междометиям (ну, эй, караул, вон, кыш, марш, тпру, ну-ка), выражающим побуждение к действию, команды, приказы.

[Междометие](http://ebooks.grsu.by/kavinkina_lang/mezhdometiya.htm)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я и пословицу вспомнил:"Как аукнется, так и откликнется".

Comment: В пословице, правда, используется другой глагол — **аукнуться.** https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F